# JFrame: setDefaultCloseOperation has no effect

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a **library method** which creates, displays, and returns a JFrame:

```
public JFrame displayChart() {
  final JFrame frame = new JFrame(windowTitle);
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    ...
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ...
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  return frame;
}
```

When I call `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` **on the returned frame**, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How do you change the close operation of a frame whose creation is not under your control?

Comment: What effect did you expect?

Comment: When I click the close button, the window closes instead of staying open.

Comment: You have to create a call to close the frame. Something like this.dispose

Comment: @AxelH quoting the question: "When I call `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` **on the returned frame**, it doesn't seem to have any effect."

Comment: @AxelH that is not my code, that is the library code over which I have no control.

Comment: Didn't get the part that it was not your library... even if it is the last thing you said. My bad !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a race condition.  If you are just calling `set` on the returned frame, then - later - their `invokeLater` will execute, overriding your change.

Put your change into another `invokeLater`:

```
public void yourMethod() {
    JFrame frame = framework.displayChart();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Swing will execute them in order, meaning yours goes last.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method and change the creation of the frame.
And if you want to the frame to get closed when you presses the red button then change

"WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE" with "WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE"
if you use WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE there won't be any affect on the jFame even after clicking on red button.

Or If your program might be getting closed someway then it won't be having any affect.

Comment: if he uses WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE then how the frame gets closed, i have used this many times